# Unable to change the Month format for DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to Convert a date and time string to DateTime variable also change the month to double digit month instead of a single digit.

Here is my current code:

```
string date = item; // 6/17/15 10:02:01 AM
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(item);
string dtm = dt.Month.ToString("MM");
string dty = dt.Year.ToString("yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(date);
Console.WriteLine("Year: {0}, Month: {1}, Day: {2}", dty, dtm, dt.Day);
Console.WriteLine(dt.TimeOfDay);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
string dtm = dt.ToString("MM");
string dty = dt.ToString("yyyy");
```

Your original code is trying to apply custom DateTime formatting to `dt.Month`, which is just an `int` and therefore the custom date format strings are not applicable to it. (Same goes for the year).

Comment: Thank you. I can choose this as the best answer after 10 mins.

Answer (score 0):

The formatting string in `ToString` method is available only for `DateTime` object. So you can just write:

```
string dtm = dt.ToString("MM");
string dty = dt.ToString("yyyy");
```

The second option is to simple `Tostring` method on `int` objects with leading zeros like:

```
string dtm = dt.ToString("D2");
string dty = dt.ToString("D2");
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is output the string that you have written in your code, try this:

```
string date = item; // 6/17/15 10:02:01 AM
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(item);
Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("'Year: 'yyyy', Month: 'MM', Day: 'dd"));
```

> Note the use of single quotes in the string

Comment: @SonerGönül, sorry, I missed the opening parenthesis. Updated now, please check. Thanks for pointing out :)